# Select arbitrary row for each group in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions

In Presto, there's an `arbitrary()` aggregate function to select any arbitrary row in a given group. If there's no `group by` clause, then I can use `distinct on`. With `group by`, every selected column must be in the `group by` or be an aggregated column. E.g.:

```
| id | foo |
| 1  | 123 |
| 1  | 321 |

select id, arbitrary(foo), count(*)
from mytable
group by id
```

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/4137)

It doesn't matter if it returns `1, 123, 2` or `1, 321, 2`. Something like `min()` or `max()` works, but it's a lot slower.

Does something like `arbitrary()` exist in Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

```
select  m.foo,b.id,b.cnt from mytable m  
join (select id, count(*) cnt
from mytable
group by id) b  using (id)  limit 1;
```

If not explicit mention `asc`, `desc` all the order is not guaranteed. Therefore in the above query the foo's appearance is arbitrary.